# getting error: 'File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/functions' on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

Whenever i try to access my rails app when it's running on localhost, I get the error:

```
File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/functions.
Load paths:
  /home/oscar/RubymineProjects/myapp/app/assets/images
  /home/oscar/RubymineProjects/myapp/app/assets/javascripts
  /home/oscar/RubymineProjects/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets
  /home/oscar/RubymineProjects/myapp/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /home/oscar/RubymineProjects/myapp/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/foundation-rails-6.1.2.0/vendor/assets/js
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/foundation-rails-6.1.2.0/vendor/assets/scss
  /var/lib/gems/2.1.0/gems/cocoon-1.2.7/app/assets/javascripts
```

I have tried fixing this using every method I could find in similar questions, but to no avail. Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


gem 'foundation_rails_helper' 

gem 'cocoon'

gem 'devise'

gem 'foundation-rails'
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'

# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.4'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
## Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'remove_turbolinks'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'

  gem 'better_errors'
end
```

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried re-bundling it?

Comment: yeah I tried that. Ended up not being able to fix the issues, had to re-clone the whole project

Comment: Yes. If I had to guess, RubyMine did something to my gem configuration that screwed it all up

Comment: I got that error when I rebuilt the Gemfile and Foundation got upgraded to '6.3.1.0' when I was previously using v5, so I had to specify the version I was using: gem 'foundation-rails', '5.5.2.1' and it went back to normal.